# Why does my GUI program display output after every click?

Tags: java

I am supposed to assume that I have a GUI program where the user selects up to three items they want to buy and then selects a shipping speed. The user then clicks a "purchase" button. My program should output a summary statement, for example:
You purchased these items at regular shipping: item1 item2 item3
You purchased these items at fast shipping: item2 item3

I need help figuring out how to prevent my program from outputting anything until the end.

I am newly exposed to these concepts so kindly give me suggestions and examples please!

Here is my code:

Comment: I think that's because you didn't override the run method just type @Override before the run mehod

Comment: @user7790438 Hello! Thank you for the suggestion:) I thought that too but it still displays an output after every click:/

Comment: Err, why are you adding that listener to all your buttons in the first place?

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you so much! I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're using the same code for every button click and not checking which button was clicked. Also, I don't see a purchase button in your code? I'll assume you meant the radio buttons, but you should use a `JButton` combined with radio buttons instead.

A way to solve this would be to make your main class implement `ActionListener` instead of a different class, like so:

```
public class OnlineShopping extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    //Variable declarations
    private JButton purchaseButton;

    public OnlineShopping() {
        //Create various elements
        purchaseButton = new JButton("Purchase");
        mainPanel.add(purchaseButton);
        purchaseButton.addActionListener(this); //Add the JFrame as a listener
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == purchaseButton) {
            if (regularShippingSpeedRadioButton.isSelected()) {
                //User has chosen to purchase at regular shipping
            } else if (fastShippingSpeedRadioButton.isSelected()) {
                //User has chosen to purchase at fast shipping
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this be in a different class?

Comment: This is all contained in your `OnlineShopping` class.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my program and the buttons are working correctly:) Im just wondering, would it make sense to have separate radio buttons for each item choice?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to purchase more than one type of item at a time? If not, make them radio buttons. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you think it answered your question. :)

Comment: Thank you so much:)) However Im not sure how to add the fast and regular shipping for the other 2 items and which variable I use when printing out the items purchased at the JTextField.

Comment: You probably would want to use the same shipping settings for all items. As for printing them out, you could check the values of the checkboxes and use those to see what to print. To set the value of the `JTextField`, you use the `.setText()` method.

Comment: I edited my code! I just need to match the format of the output in my original question and figure out why I am still able to click some of radio buttons even if they are not enabled. Thank you for the help!